# Tiles Struts /EL Expressions

Tags: struts2, tiles

I’m using Struts 2.2.3 with Tiles 2.1.4. It works absolutely fine, but now I’m trying to use EL expressions, and I can’t get it to work. In Struts2 I can  use `<s:property value="${getText('Dashboard.label')}"/>` and it retrieves the message from a bundle. I’d like to use the same on the Tiles Definition. So far I’ve added the context-param to the web.xml

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.tiles.evaluator.AttributeEvaluator</param-name>
  <param-value>org.apache.tiles.evaluator.el.ELAttributeEvaluator</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now I want to use the following expression on the definition:

```
<put-attribute name="pane-title"
               expression="${getText('Dashboard.label')}"
               cascade="true"/>
```

The issue is that when I do this, the screen fails to be created saying:

Function ':getText' not found

So I suppose I’m missing something, but I don’t know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that will work; you're trying to evaluate an OGNL expression as plain old JSP EL. I see a couple of potential solutions.

I'd try the easiest first (although it may not suit your needs in the long run): expose the value in the action, with a `getDashboardLabel` function (or whatever) that makes the `getText` call. This *should* allow a simple property query `${dashboardLabel}`.

This depends on Tiles resolving EL against how the current request resolves EL: S2 uses a thin wrapper to expose the value stack to JSP EL.

If that doesn't work or doesn't suit your needs, I think the next approach would be to see if you could create a Tiles attribute evaluator that accesses the value stack and replace the `org.apache.tiles.evaluator.el.ELAttributeEvaluator`. I'm not sure how easy/hard that would be, I'd have to check. If you can get that to evaluate OGNL the same way the existing Struts tags do, that could be pretty interesting.

Oh, you might just be able to create a JSP function library, too; I'm not really sure how that would work with the EL evaluator, though; with JSP it's pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks Dave. As you said it seems there is no easy way to get around that. At the end I just created a JSP that takes the attribute pane-title from Tiles, and uses it in a tag s:text, so I can just use that JSP in others, and setup the key in the tiles.xml. Although I think that the second option you propose would be interesting, making easier to integrate Struts2 and Tiles.

Comment: @JoseLMartinez-Avial Yep, that'd work. I put the second option of my (too-long) List of Things to Think About--I agree, it's an intriguing idea and could be pretty cool.